# OnMessageActivityAsync called twice on Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

It all worked fine till 2-3 days back , `OnMessageActivityAsync` is called twice whenever `Action.Submit` is pressed on the `carousel` card in a `Waterfall Step` on `Teams` but on emulators it works fine . Any idea what can be the issue ?

Comment: Hi @Ashish Kumar, Could you please provide the carousal card code snippet, so that we can repro at our end.

Comment: Hi @Ashish Kumar, any update on this.

Comment: Hi @Rama-MSFT I have raised the same issue with the Teams product team, while debugging turns out that the COSMOS Db was taking   a long time to respond hence due to the retry mechanism of Teams after 15 sec it was sending the card again .

Comment: @AshishKumar, glad to hear from you, now you were able to know where the exactly the issue is. Moving comments to answer section for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Moving comments to answer section for better visibility.

While debugging turns out that the COSMOS Db was taking a long time to respond hence due to the retry mechanism of Teams after 15 sec it was sending the card again .